# Launch the simulator in full screen: ios-UI Automation

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I try to start a simulator in full screen with UI automation. Is this possible? Does someone know a method to do it?

I have many errors on my tests, when I try to tap on different elements, I get this error:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().buttons()["XXX"] could not be tapped
```

I try different possibilities with index and not accessibility labels. But the problem appears sometime. I try to tap in full screen and see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Simulator.app does not support full screen mode.